# How can I play .DAT files (VideoCD format) in Android?

Tags: media-player

Is there anyway to play .DAT files (from the MPEGAV folder of a VideoCD)?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II (GT-i9100).

Comment: That's pretty obscure. You'd be best off converting them, I think.

Comment: Try Mediacoder - http://www.mediacoderhq.com

Comment: Also, try players like Rockplayer or yxPlayer on your Android device. Change the file extensions to mpg or avi and see if they'll play (provided your device has codecs or the CPU power to render via software)

Answer (score 3):

Try [Dolphin Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.broov.player).
It can play MPEG1 file format (= VCD), but cannot choose audio channel if the file is bilingual.

Answer (score 0):

Use [VPlayer Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t) or [BUZZ Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bugunsoft.BUZZPlayer).
Unlike Astro File Manager, if your file manager doesn't support custom extension handler, open .dat file with `Open As..` option and choose `video`. From pop-up, choose player app. If `Open As..` option is also not available, rename the extension of file to `avi` or `mpg`. Generally, all file managers handle these extensions. Just make sure there's no default video player set to take over the file opening & choose player app from list.

Answer (score 0):

[CX Media Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.CXMP_3) will help you to play *.dat(vcd)files

Comment: CX Media player is pulled out from playstore. Can you update the link?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the format of the file to mpg or mp4 for example: filename.DAT change to filename.mpg.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert it. Just rename its extension into .MPG using a file manager. Then, play it in MX Player. I have done it before, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Download file manager (explorer) from play store and also download mx player,,,,now, open the file manager app and locate your file. Click on it and open it in mx player.

Comment: This answer is correct, just needs better formatting and explanation.

Answer (score -1):

[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) is the best for .DAT video files.

Comment: Also technically correct, but you need to explain your answer better since MX Player doesn't find and display .DAT files, you have to manually open them using a File Manager.